# What Network should beused for Gesture Detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to create a gesture detection application with Keras and python.

I have training and testing images like this one:

[image]
[image]
[image]

There are 3 different gestures so far with about 1000 training images each.

My script already works pretty well, but the accuracy is very low.

So I am going to add my whole code because I was advised to:

```py
 #vgg16
import keras 
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Flatten, Dense, Dropout
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, ZeroPadding2D
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import cv2, numpy as np
#eigenes
import os
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

class main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.paths = ['C:\\Users\\simon\\Dev\\opencsv\\tensor\\projekt\\zu heftig\\meiii\\ASL-Finger-Spelling-Recognition-master\\eigenes'] 
        #pfad / pfäde zu den training images 
        self.x_train = []
        self.y_train = []

        self.batchsize = 1 #einstellungen
        self.epochs = 1
        self.anzahlangesten = 3

    def load_training_images(self):
            for path in self.paths:
                for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "eigenes")):
                    for filename in files:

                        fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)
                        img = cv2.imread(fullpath)


                        mean_pixel = [103.939, 116.779, 123.68]
                        img = img.astype(np.float32, copy=False)
                        #for c in range(3):
                        #    img[:, :, c] = img[:, :, c] - mean_pixel[c]
                        #img = img.transpose((2,0,1))
                        #img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
                        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                        self.x_train.append(img)
                        self.y_train.append((os.path.dirname(fullpath)).split("\\")[-1])
                        #print(self.y_train[len(self.y_train) - 1])


            self.X_train = np.array(self.x_train)
            self.Y_train = np.array(self.y_train)
            self.X_train = np.repeat(self.X_train[..., np.newaxis], 3, -1) #shape stuff
            self.Y_train = to_categorical(self.Y_train)

            self.X_train, self.X_test, self.Y_train, self.Y_test = train_test_split(self.X_train, self.Y_train, test_size=0.1, random_state=42)

            print(self.Y_train.shape, self.Y_train)

    def modelarchitektur(self):
        self.model = Sequential()

        self.model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1),input_shape=(215,240,3)))
        self.model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="same"))
        self.model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
        self.model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="same"))
        self.model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

        self.model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
        self.model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="same"))
        self.model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
        self.model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="same"))
        self.model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

        self.model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
        self.model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="same"))
        self.model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
        self.model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="same"))
        self.model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
        self.model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="same"))
        self.model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

        self.model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
        self.model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="same"))
        self.model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
        self.model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="same"))
        self.model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
        self.model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="same"))
        self.model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

        self.model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
        self.model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="same"))
        self.model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
        self.model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="same"))
        self.model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
        self.model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="same"))
        self.model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

        self.model.add(Flatten())
        self.model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
        self.model.add(Dropout(0.5))
        self.model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
        self.model.add(Dropout(0.5))
        self.model.add(Dense(self.anzahlangesten, activation='softmax'))       

    def createmodel(self):
        self.X_train = self.X_train / 255.0

        #train
        #sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
        #self.model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='categorical_crossentropy')

        #self.model.fit(self.X_train, self.Y_train, batch_size=self.batchsize, epochs=self.epochs)
        #self.model.save('projekt.model')

        #load
        self.model = keras.models.load_model('projekt.model')

    def test_accuracy(self):

        preds = self.model.predict(self.X_test)
        preds = np.argmax(preds, axis=1)
        self.Y_test = np.argmax(self.Y_test, axis=1)
        print(accuracy_score(preds, self.Y_test, normalize=True))
        print()
        print()
        print()
        print(accuracy_score(preds, self.Y_test, normalize=False))


main = main()
main.load_training_images()
main.modelarchitektur()
main.createmodel()
main.test_accuracy()
```

The accuracy is about 0.37873 of 1.

How could I increase accuracy?
What should be changed? The architecture or something else?
Or should I remove the repeat of the grayscale image and change the input of the model again?

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to start increasing the images for training because 60 for class are really very few. You can start using the models as vgg16 or others via transfer learning with keras.
However to increase accuracy for now at least 1000 images increase a lot.

I hope I was helpful

Comment: 1000 per gesture or 100 for all ?

Comment: i did what you said but it only increased the accuracy by a little
should i change the model architekture

Comment: So could i use the vgg16 model, if i train it with my data ?

Comment: if you want more help share all code because only the model is difficult.So i can help you.

Comment: so should i add the whole code to the question or like send you the code / training images with like email ?

Comment: have you change the size input of the model?If u change something from original project is normal.

Comment: yes i did 
i am actually using grayscale images that are repeated over multiple channels
if I wouldn t have done that, it wouldn t have worked to begin with

Comment: have you referr to this link [https://github.com/snrao310/ASL-Finger-Spelling-Recognition](https://github.com/snrao310/ASL-Finger-Spelling-Recognition)

Comment: if you found our help useful. Help us grow by giving a positive vote to our answers.

Answer (score 0):

Deep learning always require a lot of data. 60 images for each class is a very very vague figure. I would suggest you to first increase data set. The most simplest way to increase data set is by up sampling the images. You can invert the images and can easily up sample the data. Best of luck and cheers. 
Do following actions on each image

- Invert and add  the dataset
- Rotate each image and save in the dataset after each rotation
- Rotate the inverted image and save in the dataset after each rotation

This way you can transform each image into 8 images and hence getting a data of 480 images for each class

Comment: Okay thanks , but wouldnt IT ne simpler to Just add new Pictures ?

Comment: That would be best to, if you can manage new pictures. But apply these functions on new pictures too so you can have your dataset*8 times data, and more the data more better will be your results

Comment: I did what you said but it only increased the accuracy by a little
should I change the model architecture

Comment: Make sure first that your model isnot underfit nor overfit. After making sure that your model is neither under and over fitted that means it has fitted properly and if after fitting properly it is not giving proper accuracy on test set you can change the model architecture.

Comment: yeah i  think 1000 samples per class should be just right 
so what should i change